# dynamic radio buttons not appearing in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click in one of the table cells, radio buttons appear. when i select radio button the table cell text and background color will modify. This scenario is working fine in chrome and FF but not in IE . In IE, i could not able to see the radio buttons once clicked on the table cell.I can see the javascript error "Object Expected" in the browser console. Please suggest do i need to modify the code in order to make it work in IE. IE8 is the version I'm using.
Below is the sample code:

```
function showData(index, id, name){
    var rOptions = document.getElementById("options");
    if (rOptions == null){
      //logic
}       

   $('.one').live('click', function() {
     if($(this).hasClass("one")) {       
        deselect(index, name);  
     } 
 });
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What line gives you that error? And 1.5.2 is a really old version of jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your problem is going to be here

```
                name: name+'rOptions', 
                id: name+'rOptions' + (i+1),
                value: splitCodeValue[0],
                title: splitCodeValue[1],
                class:'one' <----
```

You need to wrap class in quotes

```
                "class" :'one'
```

Comment: By the way, for the sake of consistency it's better to just always wrap attribute names in quotes.